# setChecked() method in in checkable view fires twice every time messing with the layout

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-listview

I was working on Cal Poly lab3 (http://sites.google.com/site/androidappcourse/labs/lab-3) and everything worked as it should until I came with implementing checkable interface on expanding and collapsing items. Then it seamed that my logic was right (because the expand button text was still changing as it should) - but the layout wasn't redrawing properly - like it was collapsed when it should been expanded and looked broken.

After playing a little bit with logging I found out that every time i click on any item setChecked() method is called two times on every item in very short time-span - which messes with the drawing. First time with the old selection data - and then with the new one.

What is even more curious that I managed to kind of fix the problem by setting that setChecked() only fires every other time:

```
public void setChecked(boolean checked) 
{
    counter++;
    if (counter%2==0)
    {
        if(checked) expandJokeView();
        else collapseJokeView();
    }
    Log.d("SimpleJokeListLog", "SetChecked"+" "+checked+" "+counter+" "+m_joke.toString());

}
```

And here is how it looks like in catlog:
I start activity that displays list with items in my custom JokeView implementing checkable

```
12-18 02:58:16.598: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 1 A small
12-18 02:58:16.628: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 1 Cartoonist
12-18 02:58:16.648: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 1 I wonde
12-18 02:58:16.728: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 2 A small
12-18 02:58:16.748: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 2 Cartoonist
12-18 02:58:16.748: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 2 I wondere
```

I select first item (A small...)

```
12-18 02:59:17.628: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 3 A small 
12-18 02:59:17.628: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 3 Cartoonis
12-18 02:59:17.628: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 3 I wondere
12-18 02:59:17.838: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked true 4 A small boy
12-18 02:59:17.847: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 4 Cartoonist
12-18 02:59:17.858: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 4 I wondered
```

I select second one

```
12-18 02:59:24.768: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked true 5 A small boy 
12-18 02:59:24.768: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 5 Cartoonist 
12-18 02:59:24.768: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 5 I wondered w
12-18 02:59:24.968: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 6 A small
12-18 02:59:24.968: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked true 6 Cartooni
12-18 02:59:24.978: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 6 I wonde
```

Third one

```
12-18 02:59:27.828: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 7 A small
12-18 02:59:27.838: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked true 7 Cartoonis
12-18 02:59:27.838: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 7 I wonder
12-18 02:59:28.048: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 8 A small 
12-18 02:59:28.058: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 8 Cartooni
12-18 02:59:28.068: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked true 8 I wondered
```

Again third one (even this time without this counter thingy it doesn't draw properly):

```
12-18 02:59:31.197: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 9 A small b
12-18 02:59:31.197: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 9 Cartoonist
12-18 02:59:31.197: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked true 9 I wondered 
12-18 02:59:31.417: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 10 A small bo
12-18 02:59:31.417: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked false 10 Cartoonist f
12-18 02:59:31.427: D/SimpleJokeListLog(742): SetChecked true 10 I wondered why
```

Answer (score 3):

I m stuck on this promlem last 3 or 4 hours, at the end i tried remove setChecked() calls from extend and collapse methods (don`t remember why i placed them there...). Maybe it helps you, here is my snippet code:

```
private void collapseRow() {
    mText.setMaxLines(2);
    mText.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    mExpand.setText(COllAPS);
    mWiki.setVisibility(GONE);
    requestLayout();
    state = COLLAPSED;


}
private void expandRow() {
    mText.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    mText.setEllipsize(null);
    mExpand.setText(EXPAND);
    mWiki.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    requestLayout();
    state = EXPANDED;

}
private void setData() {
    mText.setText(mItem.getDate());
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
        Log.d("isChecked", "!!!!!!!");
        return mChecked;

}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean state) {
    count++;

    if (state)
        expandRow();
    else
        collapseRow();

    Log.d("setChecked", ""+ state + "" + count);
}

@Override
public void toggle() {
    Log.d("toggle", "!!!!!!!");
    setChecked(!mChecked);

}
```

Now, all work perfectly: no multiple calls of setChecked, and ListItems open and close like they should.